# Are displacement maps supported in SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit

I am creating a globe and have a height map image as well as a satellite image for the displacement and textures respectively. I have created an SCNSphere and can apply the texture without issue, however I am unable to use the height map.

SCNMaterial supports normal maps via its normal property (not what I'm after though), and appears to support displacement maps via its displacement property. However, the displacement property has a blank documentation page, and appears to do nothing.

While it is possible to "convert" a height map to a normal map, this results in a normal map and therefore does not create new geometry and so is not a solution. That is, viewing a subset of the globe and turning the camera would not show the side of the mountain but instead a smooth sphere.

Currently, I can create an object using the height map in Cinema 4D, which adds a step and while it works, I'm hoping to use SceneKit directly.

Update: This video from WWDC 2017 indicates the feature should in fact work (24:00 into the video):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/

Answer (score 1):

I’ve noticed that maps sometimes need a high intensity to work. In one case I downloaded a high res displacement map and it didn’t show anything until I set the intensity above 3000.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5472243/leerie-simpson I having no luck getting these working at all. Can you post sample sample code maybe? or contact me directly mark.lucking@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is displacement maps are not supported in the simulator, however they do work on an actual device.

The displacement maps generate only very rough geometry based on the input height map, which seems unrelated to the resolution of the geometry SceneKit generates unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I’m no expert and I’m definitely having trouble utilizing height maps, normal maps, light maps, and shadow maps.... but I think you’ll want to check out SCNShadable, SCNProgram, and SCNTechnique on the Apple Developer website.

If the maps don’t work... maybe learning to write shaders will.